# What's does the user daemon mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I was just checking my VPS. I am using Apache server and I found user daemon is taking 15-30% CPU use

[User Daemon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWmcv.png)

Answer (score 1):

It’s a legacy system account for running processes, [as seen here](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/usernames.html). In your particular instance it appears to be running php-fpm, so it is probably related to a web server stack.